# Set style for pandas without changing its type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to change the style of my pandas without changing its type

Here a small example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[19, 439],[19, 439]], columns=['COOL','NOTCOOL'])
def colour_col(col):
    if col.name == 'COOL':    
        return ['background-color: red'  for c in col.values]
df = df.style.apply(colour_col)
df
```

[image]

But, obviously df is now a pandas.io.formats.style.Styler,
so I can not have access to 'COOL' column anymore

```
df['COOL']
TypeError: 'Styler' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I customize my pandas only when it is displayed ?

Comment: Why do you assign the return value to `df`? Running `df.style.apply(colour_col)` should modify the `Styler` object directly see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html?highlight=style%20apply

Comment: There is a SO question regarding changing style permanently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56176720/changing-style-of-pandas-dataframe-permanently Maybe that's what you're after?

Comment: True. But behind that I have a function. I want  to have the possibility to return a pimped pandas when one want to display it or a pandas when one want to save it into an other variable (to be able to make some calculation after)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to make a function which print (display) the pandas  pimped and return the pandas Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[19, 439],[19, 439]], columns=['COOL','NOTCOOL'])

def toto(mypd):
    def colour_col(col):
        if col.name == 'COOL':    
            return ['background-color: red'  for c in col.values]
    display(mypd.style.apply(colour_col))
    return mypd
A=toto(df)
A['COOL']
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: the simplest solution is to create a dataframe, `df` and not overwrite it. Then it is always available as an object, you do not need to "return" it. The styler can display in any customised form you like with one call: `df.style.pipe(my_custom)`